# Django - serializer validation with foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have two models to represent a Student and his Contact.

```
class Contact(models.Model):
  phone_num = models.IntegerField()
  email = models.TextField()

class Student(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()
  age = models.IntegerField()
  contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
```

The data structure that I needed to return with:

```
{
  name: 'Peter',
  age: 18,
  contact: {
    phone_num: 1234567890,
    email: 'peter123@gmail.com'
  }
}
```

In my post request, I receive a json format data:

```
{
  name: 'Mary',
  age: 19,
  phone_num: 9876543210,
  email: mary987@gmail.com
}
```

I'm trying to create a serializer for data validation.

Contact:

```
class ContactSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Contact
    exclude = ('id',)
```

Student:

```
class StudentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  contact = ContactSerializer()

  class Meta:
    model = Student
    exclude = ('id',)
```

I tried to put the post request data into the serializer and check if it's valid.

```
data = {
  name: 'Mary',
  age: 19,
  phone_num: 9876543210,
  email: mary987@gmail.com
}
student = StudentSerializer(data=data)
student.is_valid()
// It returns false.
print(student.errors)
// Print: {'contact': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

How can I valid my data with this data structure?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to first create the data in contact table becuase student is having it as a foreign key.
One of the convenient way to do this will be to receive the json in this format

`{
  name: 'Mary',
  age: 19,
  contact: {
           phone_num: 9876543210,
           email: mary987@gmail.com
    }
}`

In your views.py

`

```
context = {
    phone_num: 9876543210,
    email: mary987@gmail.com
}

serializer = ContactSerializer(data=request.data['contact'))
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save     #saved contact data first

data = request.data
data['contact']=serializer.data['id']

serializer = StudentSerializer(data=data)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save
return Response(serializer.data)
```

`

In serializers.py

```
class StudentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  contact = ContactSerializer()

  class Meta:
    model = Student

class ContactSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Contact`
```

Is there anything specific that you want to hide the ID field?

Answer (score 0):

It says `contact` is required field. If you want to pass contact id in data then
Write like following,

```
class StudentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  contact = ContactSerializer(read_only=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Student
    exclude = ('id',)

  def create(self, attrs):
    instance = super(StudentSerializer, self).create(attrs)
    instance.contact = self.initial_data.get('contact')
    instance.save()
```